# Typo3 - Create pages and content elements programmatically through Ajax/Front-End

Tags: ajax, typo3, headless

Is there a way to create new pages or content elements programmatically through Ajax from a headless front-end?
I'm just trying to understand Typo3 possibilities and limits.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. Do you have some admins that are allowed to create pages and content elements via FrontEnd and not in Backend?

Comment: Maybe you want to check the [TYPO3 PWA and headless initiative](https://typo3.org/community/teams/typo3-development/initiatives/pwa). The guys of Macopedia might provide useful hints in the TYPO3 Slack.

Comment: Create content as in WordPress where you can create new articles with ajax through the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You will have to use Middlewares (TYPO3 >= 9).

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestHandling/Index.html

Basically you register your Middleware and then you evaluate what you want to do. For example you can set a GET or POST parameter with a key & a value
that look like this: `?object=article` and according to what you want to do, you call the class that handles the data. After that, you can return a json response and you are solid.

Hope it helped,

Best regards